# How do I filter by node ID in views?

Tags: views, 8, entities, nodes

I am trying to add Node ID in contextual filters but it seems there isn't Node ID anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use `content ID`, which is now the same thing.

That is the one to use as contextual filter, in Drupal 8.

Comment: That is Correct. Node ID has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

In view contextual filters add Node Id through content id .[image]